# How can I programatically hide or suppress the search suggestions list?

Tags: java, android, android-searchmanager

How can I programatically hide the list of suggestions that pops up up below the `SearchView`?

There are times when I'd like the `SearchView` to not be inconified and to not have focus. I can do this both using the `setIconified(false)` and the `clearFocus()` methods respectively, but if the `SearchView` has any text in it, it will display the list of a search suggestions and I need to hide/suppress that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set an `OnQueryTextListener` to your search view, and return `true` on `onQueryTextChange` when you don't want any suggestions to show up.

Answer (score 2):

`searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(null);` did that trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you've set a `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` on your `SearchView`, you can return `false` in `onQueryTextSubmit`.

This will make sure suggestions get closed/hidden whenever the user submits the search query (by clicking on a suggestion or the "search" button on the keyboard).